# how can I decode android contacts?

Tags: java, android

when I extract from the cursor the value for a contact's first name the special characters get transformed into ?:

```
    if(!d.isNull(CURSOR_FIRST_NAME)){  cm.first = d.getString(CURSOR_FIRST_NAME);}
```

- so can you help me figure out which encoding is used by the android contacts so that I can extract the exact string and encode it to UTF-8?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `URLDecoder.decode()` method:

```
import java.net.URLDecoder;


    try {  
    if(!d.isNull(CURSOR_FIRST_NAME)){cm.first = URLDecoder.decode(d.getString(CURSOR_FIRST_NAME, "UTF-8");}    
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    Log.("UnsupportedEncodingException ", e.getMessage());
    }
```

Comment: Ty, that did the trick for me, previously I was using getBytes(UTF-8) but to no avail.. the other part of the problem was I needed to encode it back in order to send it to the Sever with  cm.first = URLEncoder.encode(cm.first, "UTF-8");